# Wait for forEach to complete before returning value - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, ionic-framework, execution

**Overview:**
I'm creating an app using ionic framework and AngularJS. The App has 2 forms where user can upload images. In first form, image upload field allows to upload only one image and second form image upload field allows to upload more than one images. After user uploads images I'm showing preview to user right below image field. Then user click on "Save", which calls Web Service (defined into factory) to upload images to site. The Service function implements $q, so that form submission can continue only after uploading images. This is working fine.

**Problem:**
When uploading multiple images, I'm calling another helper function in controller which loop (forEach) over file data and call file save function for each file. But the execution in this helper function doesn't wait for forEach loop to complete. This is allowing me to get first file details of file saved, but not remaining saved files details.

Here is code I'm using for uploading file:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($q) {
  // Upload single file.
  $scope.fileUpload = function(fileData) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (angular.isUndefined(fileData) || angular.isUndefined(fileData.dataURL)) {
      deferred.resolve("No new upload found.");
    }
    else {
      var filedata = {
        "file" : {
          file: (fileData.dataURL).replace(/^data:image\/[A-Za-z]{3,4};base64,+/g, ''),
          filename: fileData.file.name,
        },
      };
      AuthServiceContent.uploadNewFile(filedata).then(function(response) {
        deferred.resolve(response);
      }, function(response) {
        deferred.reject(response);
      });
    }
    return deferred.promise;
  };

  // Upload multiple files.
  $scope.fileUploadMultiple = function(data) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var fileUploadStatus = [];
    if (angular.isUndefined(data) || angular.isUndefined(data[0])) {
      deferred.reject("No new upload found.");
    }
    else {
      angular.forEach(data, function(fileData, index) {
        $scope.fileUpload(fileData).then(function(response) {
          fileUploadStatus[index] = response;
        }, function(response) {
        });
      });
    }

    return (!angular.isUndefined(fileUploadStatus) ? deferred.resolve(fileUploadStatus) : deferred.reject(fileUploadStatus));
  };

  $scope.createContent = function(formData) {
    $scope.fileUploadMultiple(formData.image).then(function(response) {
      if (angular.isObject(response)) {
        angular.forEach(response, function(fileData, index) {
          console.log(fileData);
          formData.image.und = [{'fid' : fileData.fid}];
        });
        console.log(formData);
      }
      else {
      }
    }, function(err) {
      console.log("updates failed!!!");
    });
    return;
  };
})

.factory('AuthServiceContent', function($q, $http, DEFAULT) {
  var service_content = {
    uploadNewFile: function(fileData) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http.post(DEFAULT.serviceURL + 'file', JSON.stringify(fileData), {
        headers : {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Cookie': 'cookieData',
        }
      })
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
      })
      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        deferred.reject(data);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };

  return service_content;
});
```

I've been trying this for more than 2 days and find similar issue, but its not working.

**Updates:**
I got this working by adding extra check in loop, here is updated function in controller to upload multiple images.

```
  $scope.fileUploadMultiple = function(data) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var fileUploadStatus = [];
    if (angular.isUndefined(data) || angular.isUndefined(data[0])) {
      deferred.reject("No new upload found.");
    }
    else {
      var dataLength = (data.length - 1);

      angular.forEach(data, function(fileData, index) {
        $scope.fileUpload(fileData).then(function(response) {
          fileUploadStatus[index] = response;
          // Check if we are at last element. If yes, then return status
          // Return deffered status on last element.
          if (dataLength == index) {
            deferred.resolve(fileUploadStatus);
          }
        }, function(response) {
          // Check if we are at last element. If yes, then return status
          // Return deffered status on last element.
          if (dataLength == index) {
            deferred.reject(fileUploadStatus);
          }
        });
      });
    }

    return deferred.promise;
  };
```

Comment: I tried you updated code. If you upload multiple files and the last is the smallest, it fires the *resolve*. The bigger files are not in the *fileUploadStatus*.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have only one promise and are resolving it as soon as the first call uploaded file returns its results.

Save all the promises in an array and then try $q.all:

```
var promises = [];
angular.forEach(data, function(fileData, index) {
    promises.push($scope.fileUpload(fileData));
});

$q.all(promises).then(function(results) {
   // loop through the results, one for each promise, and do what you need
})
```

or just return `$q.all(promises)` and let the application code handle the results.

The big problem with $q.all is that it just gives and error if ANY of the promises is rejected.  If you still want to handle the results for each promise, I use an implementation of $q.allSettled (I think I use [this implementation](http://www.codeducky.org/q-allsettled/).  That returns a response for each promise -- either success or failure -- with the error message or the returned data so that I can then handle the results of each promise separately.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Beartums. I've already tried doing $q.all(). it didn't worked as well. Let me try with eg. you've suggested

Comment: Can you tell me what the symptoms are when you use $q.all?  Does the callback function fire?  What is the data the it receives?

Comment: Yes, callback function is called when using $q.all, but I receive only first record in array during loop. To fix this I've added condition to check if current row is last, if yes then only I'm setting deferred.resolve()/reject().

Comment: Can you update the question to show the code as it is now?  If so, ping me here in the comments so I know to have a look

Comment: I've already updated question with latest code, under "Updates" section

Comment: Didn't see that.  It's an excellent solution.  The only downside to that is that the responses won't necessarily be in the order of the fileData objects -- which is no big deal at all if you don't need the correlation.

Comment: I've not checked order of images after attaching, will check and update here. But when looping to file data I'll be getting same order, right?

Comment: Looking at the code again, you should be fine.  Well done.

Answer (score 0):

The updated code in the answer is not working. If the last file is the smallest, it fires the *resolve* immediately after it's been uploaded. I use instead a fileIsUplaoded counter.

```
  $scope.fileUploadMultiple = function(data) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var fileUploadStatus = [];
    if (angular.isUndefined(data) || angular.isUndefined(data[0])) {
      deferred.reject("No new upload found.");
    }
    else {
      var uploadCount = data.length;

      angular.forEach(data, function(fileData, index) {
        $scope.fileUpload(fileData).then(function(response) {
          // if a file is uploaded reduce the uploadCount by 1
          uploadCount --;
          fileUploadStatus[index] = response;
          // Check if we are at last element. If yes, then return status
          // Return deffered status on last element.
          if (uploadCount == 0) {
            deferred.resolve(fileUploadStatus);
          }
        }, function(response) {
          // if a file is not uploaded reduce the uploadCount by 1
          uploadCount --;
          // Check if we are at last element. If yes, then return status
          // Return deffered status on last element.
          if (uploadCount == 0) {
            deferred.reject(fileUploadStatus);
          }
        });
      });
    }

    return deferred.promise;
  };
```