# AngularJs : Multiple Calls for $http service

Tags: angularjs, json, http

this is my code :

```
        var updateScreen = function() {
          $http.get("http://localhost:5000").then(function(response){
          $scope.numSerie = response.data.refDetail.Num_Serie;

          $http.get("data/tempsgammes.json").then(function(res){
            $scope.time = res.data[$scope.numSerie].temps;
            console.log($scope.time)
          })

         console.log($scope.time)
       }
```

The first $http.get("http://localhost:5000") returns a list of details that I use in the rest of the code, what interests us is the variable **numSerie**.

Depending on the value of **numSerie**, another $http.get("data/tempsgammes.json") will be executed to extract the **time** for this **numSerie** from a JSON file.

The problem is I cannot get access to the **$scope.time** only in the second call for $http. The first console.log() gave me the desired result, but the second one **undefined**.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: The console.log($scope.time) is being called 2 times. You see the first one is giving the right value and the second one isn't.
It is because of the async behaviour of "then". It is not intuitive but the second console.log($scope.time) is being called before the "then" has finished, this is why it shows "undefined".

**Edit 2**: Try the following to probe the execution order on async operations

```
 $http.get("data/tempsgammes.json").then(function(response){
   alert('first');       // <--- This will be called first
   .then(function(res){  
      alert('third!');   // <--- This will be called third
 });
 alert('second!');       // <--- This will be called second
```

Yes, you can use $scope.time anywhere, but if you try to use it bellow of the "then", it will not be defined yet. You can put somewhere in your view {{$scope.time}} and probe that it will be defined outside of the $http.get

---

If you get undefined is probable that the index of res.data[$scope.numSerie] is out of bounds.

First check if you have some error using the developer tools of your browser. $scope.numSerie seems to be the culprit here, check its value or provide more detail

Comment: everything is fine and the res.data[$scope.numSerie] isn't out of bounds, $scope.numSerie it's not a culprit too, $scope.numSerie have the desired value. The only problem is I can't use the $scope.time out from $http.get()

Comment: Oh, I see. In the momment you call console.log($scope.Time), the async call is still in progress. Put console.log($scope.Time) in the inner http$.get() and you should see the value.

Comment: I know that i see the value in the inner, I want to use it outside

Comment: To clarify a little (now I see you have the call inside and outside), surely only the "inside" one is working. This is the expected behaviour on async calls. When you call http$.get, the code bellow continues without waiting for the get result (then). So it is normal that $scope.Time is undefined outside (in that instant)

Comment: So, what should I do ? I need the value to work with after, I mean outside

Comment: Shoul not be a problem, but depends on what you need. "Then" instruction is telling "do this with the result only when you have the result". I think you can ignore what is outside of the $get. Consider everything inside the $get as the normal flow and everything outside as "parallel" operations. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36457499/calling-multiple-http-services-in-a-for-loop-from-angularjs-controller-and-serv?rq=1. The problem there is more complex, but basically is also about this frequent async confusion - "success" is doing the same role as your "then" implementation

Comment: Is there any way to use $scope.time in my js code and outside $http.get() ?

Comment: If you need to chain to other operations, any other code should be called from inside the get. Otherwise you'll have sync problems

Comment: And... I don't think you'll need it yet, but if you really don't want to put the calls inside the $get, you could find a solution using the $q directive: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q